# Control background bound to image not updating

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

Note: This is for a Windows RT App (Windows Store app).

I am having a strange issue when I am trying to bind the background of a button to an image that is stored on the device.

Basically my set up is as follows:

I have a button that, when pressed, presents a flyout that has a canvas in which the user can draw something using an `InkManager`. Once the flyout closes, it saves that ink data to a .png file.

The button itself has its `Background` bound to the path of the .png file which does implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

XAML:

```
<Button.Background>
    <Binding Converter="{StaticResource FileNameToImage}" Path="PicFilePath"/>
</Button.Background>
```

Code behind:

```
public string PicFilePath
{
    get { return picFilePath; }
    set
    {
        //This is commented out because I want to reuse the same file name, which would cause this to not notify that the property was changed.
        //if (value == picFilePath) return;
        picFilePath = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

It then uses a converter to convert that path to an `ImageBrush` that has that image as its background:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
{
    try
    {
        string fileName = value.ToString();
        var brush = new ImageBrush();
        Uri sigUri = new Uri(fileName);
        brush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(sigUri);
        return brush;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        var brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        return brush;
    }
}
```

My issue is stemming from the fact that I am attempting to reuse the same file name when I create the file after the user finishes drawing:

```
StorageFile myMerge = await currSessionFolder.CreateFileAsync(PicFileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

oStream = await myMerge.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
if (oStream != null)
{
    await mainInkManager.SaveAsync(oStream);
}
//Here is where I reset the data context's PicFilePath
globalContext.PicFilePath = myMerge.Path;
```

This works the first time through but if I go back and add more strokes to the canvas and close it, the button retains the same background that it had before, even though I can step through the code and verify that it is going through the `OnPropertyChanged` and convert process which should give it a new `ImageBrush` for the background. I can even browse the file system to the actual png file and see that it is updated with the new strokes before the button is supposed to update.

On top of that this works 100% as I intend it to if I use a unique file name for each modification of the canvas. So if I draw a smiley face and save it as `smiley.png`, when I close the flyout the button will update with that image. If I open it back up and save it as `smiley2.png` and close it, it updates the button just fine. My issue is that I don't want to have to resave the image with a new name every time and I can't see why this isn't working when I reuse the same file name.

Any ideas?

Comment: Even if you raise the PropertyChanged event, the actual property value hasn't changed if you reuse the file name, so the binding won't be triggered. You may change the type of your property from string to ImageBrush (or ImageSource), and thus also avoid the converter.

Comment: Definitely +1 to ditching the converter.

Comment: Or just set the PicFilePath property to null, before setting it again to the old value.